# Error in JavaScript confirm message

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, confirmation

I am new to JavaScript. I cannot find the error of this code.

```
<td class="paid">
  <a href="invoice.php?id=<?php echo $invoice_result['id']; ?>" onclick="confirm()">
    <img src="images/view_3.gif"/>
  </a>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function confirm() {
   if (confirm("Do you realy want do delete this vehicle?")) {
     return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
 }
</script>
```

help me to find my error..

Comment: What is the error that needs to be found? Please explain your issue clearly and what is the point where you are facing an error

Comment: you cannot name  your function using reserved names...

Comment: [Reserved words in javascript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check with this

```
<td class="paid"><a href="invoice.php?id=<?php echo $invoice_result['id']; ?>" onclick="confirmChk()"><img src="images/view_3.gif"/></a></td>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmChk(){
    if(confirm("Do you realy want do delete this vehicle?")){
    return true;
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
    }
    </script>
```

NB:The problem was with your function name I changed it **confirm** to **confirmChk**

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to overload "confirm" function, which is built-in function and thus your code is not working. Change the name of your function from `confirm` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<td class="paid">
<span onclick="return confirm('Do you realy want do delete this vehicle?')">
<a href="invoice.php?id=<?php echo $invoice_result['id']; ?>"><img src="images/view_3.gif"/></a>
</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your function to something else than confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
onClick="return confirm('Do you realy want do delete this vehicle?');"
```

..

```
<td class="paid"><a href="invoice.php?id=<?php echo $invoice_result['id']; ?>"
onClick="return confirm('Do you realy want do delete this vehicle?');">
<img src="images/view_3.gif"/></a></td>
```

The error happened to you cos of the reserved word `confirm`.

chek this too [Reserved words in javascript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm